# Set an expiry date to self-destruct downloaded M365 documents

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, retention

Is it possible to set an expiration date on M365 documents downloaded from a SharePoint library?

Essentially, I'd like to ensure that our sales and marketing teams are always sharing updated content with our prospective customers. Is there a way to set a self-destruct button within a document so that it's impossible to open/share/email past a certain date?

An added bonus would be the ability to create an alert within the application instructed the user to download a new copy of the file from the doc library on SharePoint as well.

Comment: Why would they be downloading the file rather than just opening the file directly from SharePoint? Downloading the file creates a copy of the file on their file system but if they open it straight from SharePoint, they are always seeing the latest version.

Comment: They definitely shouldn't be downloading most of the files (I plan on restricting this in the  SP settings.) But we have team members that consistently download versions of sales or marketing assets specifically to make changes and 'perfect' their own copies.

We're of course in the process of centralizing everything, but I know this will be a difficult habit to break, so was hoping to force the behavior.

Comment: Have they tried syncing the library to their machine using OneDrive for Business? Most people download files for offline access.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, we can't set expiration date in sharepoint to self-destruct download , because once the file is downloaded, it will be stored in personal local. Even if you cancel the permission later, you can still see the downloaded documents.

But you can set alert as a workaround. Send email alerts to prospective customers when your documentation is updated（As shown below）.
[image]

---

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: Hi @Grokante, Is there any progress on this thread? Please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thank you for responding. This aligns with my hunch on the matter.

When I worked at MSFT, I would download and share that new file with others. Then at some later date, when attempting to do the same thing, I've gotten a notification about the file being protected by AIP and prevented the action. (Only came across this 2-3 times).

Recently, a member of IT shared that our computers are completely mirrored to OneDrive as of the last update. "Nothing is local on your comps anymore." Was hoping that if this is true, then perhaps there was a way to accomplish a file self-destruct.